Why do we say that finding a string in a hash table is O(1)?

let us say the length of the string is L. When we are inserting this into a hash table (let us say we are using separate chaining), first of all the hash for the string is computed. How is the insertion into the hash table O(1), should'nt it be O(L) as time for computing the hash of a string grows with string size?

after the hash is computed, then the string is stored in the hash table. Won't this copying also take O(L)?

when the string is looked up in the hash table, how can it be a constant operation? Because again, the hash for the string is computed, and then at the computed bucket the string is compared which should also be O(L) in the worst case.


Please, can someone explain this? What am I missing?
I tried asking ChatGPT, and also looked for solutions on the websites, but they were conflicting. ChatGPT says it will be O(L), but some websites say it will be O(1).

Big O is based on the size of the container, not the element being added.

When talking about inserting/finding something in a hash table, we want to know the complexity of the operation in relation to the hash tables size, not the object you're actually storing in it.

@tkausl hey. thanks for answering. i am asking about the complexity of the operations for hash table such as insertion, contains etc.

Complexity applies to some operations (better to explicitly tell which one, even if most of the time it might be omitted). O(1) here applies to the number of Key/node comparaison.

"some websites were saying": please provide a reputable source that says this.

btw, O(L) is O(1) because you have a container of strings, not a string of containers (or whatever) -- the variable is the number of elements of container, not the length of the string.

When you go to a store you buy a good for O(1) time regardless of how long time is spent for producing and delivering this good to a store.

@3CxEZiVlQ by that logic any type of problem we solve is solved in O(1) lmao

Also, if you have extremely long strings, perhaps a hash-table with those strings as keys are not the best idea. The O(1) just says that the number of keys has little effect, not that the operation takes zero time.

@The Noobest Guy -- do you understand that big-O is the lim(f(n)) with n->∞ ? What's n here? -- It's not the string size, it's the container size.

@Gene if we are finding time complexity of a function f(n) with respect to size of input n then the time complexity will be O(f(n)), here the input size will be of string no yes the container will also come into account but wont the main factor be the size of the string L ?

@TheNoobestGuy Based on your latest comment what you are asking about is the 'big O' notation for the time complexity of the string hashing algorithm -- nothing to do with the operations on the container itself.

Note: Lua implementation, as well in our company framework, long strings are not fully hashed, but only up to 32 characters, sampled regularly the string. But true, we still need to run strcmp along the whole string if hashes are the same to confirm that strings are equal.

The C++ standard has this to say:

[container.requirements.general]/2 All of the complexity requirements in this Clause are stated solely in terms of the number of operations on the contained objects. [Example: The copy constructor of type vector<vector<int>> has linear complexity, even though the complexity of copying each contained vector<int> is itself linear. —end example]

Similarly, hash(string of length L) is treated as one operation on the contained object for purposes of discussing the complexity of operations on hash-based containers, even though actually computing the hash may take the amount of wall time proportional to L.
